# $rootScope value undefined?

Tags: angularjs

This is My Controller data. coupon.offer is ng-model to api. the response got an array. $rootScope.Result is array of data but the $rootScope.Result.offerprice=undefined. how to get the this data

```
mainCtrl.controller("OrderController",function($scope,$rootScope){
couponres=$resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/promocode? code="+$rootScope.coupon.offer)
   if($scope.Total()>=400) 
    {  
       $rootScope.Result=couponres.get(function(data){
       console.log(data);
       return data;
   });
  console.log($rootScope.Result);
   console.log($rootScope.Result.offerprice)
```

Response:

```
Resource {offerid: "6", offerprice: "30", $promise: Promise, $resolved: true}
offerprice:
undefined
```

i use this

```
var couponres=$resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/promocode?code="+$rootScope.coupon.offer)
   if($scope.Total()>=400)

    {  
 $rootScope.Result=couponres.get().$promise.then(function(data){
       console.log(data);

       return data;

   });}
```

but not working
please provide solution for this

Comment: `$resource` is AJAX which is asynchronous by definition. You can't access the data before the request has completed

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to log the response of the AJAX request right after you have sent the request. That can't work. The first A in AJAX means *Asynchronous*.

So the response is not available yet at that time. Move your two log statements inside the callback function where you're already logging `data`.

Answer (score -1):

Angular $resource service returns a promise so you can not 
have data as soon as you send request!

while you are using an asynchronous function and right 
after that, you are logging `$rootScope.Result`  which 
is not resolved yet and there for returns undefined!

you can have the data after the promise is resolved:

```
couponres.get().$promise.then(function(response) {

   $rootScope.Result = response.data;
    console.log($rootScope.Result);
    console.log($rootScope.Result.offerprice);   
});
```

**Update:**

now! you can use it in your view.

**for example :**

```
<h1>
{{Result.offerprice}}
</h1>
```

Comment: Not really true. `$resource` itself returns an array or object which is empty until request completes. You can use a promise but not the way you have shown

Comment: Yes. you are right. edited the answer. let me know if it's true. Thanks

Comment: Still doesn't explain why using the callback isn't working for OP. The `console.log()` will be same using both methods

Comment: I think  the way you are  using the promise is wrong. nothing more.

Comment: You just can't log $rootScope outside promise callback function. But it Will be available in your view, the way I showed it!

Comment: how i use the offerprice outstde

Comment: @SrinivasAppQube You need to understand the concept of `asynchronous`. You can't access that data until the request is completed

Comment: please provide code how to get offerprice outside of the function. i use $promise.then(function(data){}) but not working on out side.

Comment: That's the point  @SrinivasAppQube!  you should use it inside the function! Improve your question, show me some code. where do you want to use it?

Comment: Ok. Thank You Problem Solved.@Ahmad Mobaraki